# How do you use exclude in salt

Tags: salt-stack

I'm trying to use the following block in a salt state

```
exclude:
  - id: nopesir
```

But this is generating the following stack trace.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/bin/salt-call", line 11, in <module> salt_call()
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/salt/scripts.py", line 400, in salt_call
client.run()
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/salt/cli/call.py", line 57, in run
caller.run()
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/salt/cli/caller.py", line 134, in run
ret = self.call()
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/salt/cli/caller.py", line 212, in call
ret['return'] = func(*args, **kwargs)
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/salt/modules/state.py", line 749, in apply_
return highstate(**kwargs)
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/salt/modules/state.py", line 1055, in highstate
orchestration_jid=orchestration_jid)
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/salt/state.py", line 3881, in call_highstate
return self.state.call_high(high, orchestration_jid)
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/salt/state.py", line 2693, in call_high
high, req_in_errors = self.requisite_in(high)
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/salt/state.py", line 1560, in requisite_in
if not state.startswith('__')]:
AttributeError: 'OrderedDict' object has no attribute 'startswith'
```

I'm trying to follow the example from [the documentation](https://docs.saltstack.com/en/latest/ref/states/include.html#exclude) but I must be overlooking something.

I'm using version 2018.3.0.

Comment: you need to provide absolute path for `nopesir`